# WiX: RemoveExistingProducts + ADDLOCAL

Tags: wix, wix2

I'm using Wix 2. I am using `RemoveExistingProducts`, but want to keep my previously installed features. In addition, I'd like to add new features via `ADDLOCAL` parameters given via command line.
However, according to [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/aa370839%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) `ADDLOCAL` does set the `Preselected` flag.

Therefore `MigrateFeatureStates` does not fire:

```
Skipping MigrateFeatureStates action: feature settings already made
```

Is there a possibility to use them both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, not both. The documentation is pretty clear that `ADDLOCAL` (and all the other feature state controls via the command-line Properterties) take over the selection manager. It, unfortunately, makes using the command-line to control feature states very tricky.